# For fixed $a\in \Bbb{R}^d$ show that the family of functions $f_r (x)$ on $\Bbb{R}^d$ defined by

Tags: lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

This is a problem from Harmonic Analysis, I was reading about Fourier Transform, more likely about Singular Integrals. 
Can anyone help me to prove this problem?

$f_r(x)= \frac{1}{|B(a, r)|}\chi B(a, r) (x)$

forms an approximate identity as $r\rightarrow 0. $

This term was used in Lebesgue's differentiation theorem's proof. 
Also no idea bout the term $\chi$.

in my opinion

$f_r(x)= \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)}f(y)dy$

thank you

Comment: What does "xed" mean in the title? Also when your line with $f_r(x)$ is not a definition but an identity that we should prove, then what is the definition of $f_r(x)$ in the first place?

Comment: I have added the function of $f_r(x). $ I think that might be right.